# how to avoid repetition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

How can i avoid this repetitious code?
I'm new to javascript.
I need to call the same function with different params like 100 times,
and also have like 100 different getElementBys

```
(function() {

    var ok, publicSessionID, sms, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;

    var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        subscribe_key: '',
        publish_key: ''
    });


    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    };

    var publicSessionID = getParameterByName('tv') || 'default';
    var sms = getParameterByName('sms') || 'default';
    var a = document.getElementById("channel1");
    var b = document.getElementById("channel2");
    var c = document.getElementById("channel3");


    d.onclick = function() {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: publicSessionID,
            message: {
                "action": "tv.new.channel.4"
            }
            uuid: sms,
            callback: function(info) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            }
        })
        return false;
    };

    e.onclick = function() {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: publicSessionID,
            message: {
                "action": "tv.new.channel.5"
            }
            uuid: sms,
            callback: function(info) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    f.onclick = function() {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: publicSessionID,
            message: {
                "action": "tv.new.channel.6"
            }
            uuid: sms,
            callback: function(info) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
})()
```

var a, through z is going to get repetitious
and
a.onclick = function () {} is getting repitious, whats some more efficent ways to do this in js?

thanks

Comment: Write a function that does that, accepting as arguments what is changeable. Learn more about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions.

Comment: I think you're better of using classes instead of ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pubnub (channel) {
    pubnub.publish({
        channel : publicSessionID,
        message : {"action": "tv.new.channel.5"} //use channel here
            uuid : sms ,
            callback : function(info) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
        }           
    });     
    return false;
};
```

Just make it a function with a channel parameter, and call it like

```
e.onclick = function() { pubnub(5); }
```

Just a note, `onclick` only allows one event, so consider using `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Write a function generator,

```
function generatorFunction(channel) {
    return function() {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: publicSessionID,
            message: {
                "action": channel
            }
            uuid: sms,
            callback: function(info) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
};
```

and invoke that with the channel as an argument to get a new function with the channel specified

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 26; i += 1) {
    var currentChannel = document.getElementById("channel" + i);
    currentChannel.onclick = generatorFunction("tv.new.channel." + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be able to take advantage of a naming convention here to avoid typing out 100 calls to getElementById;

```
var elements = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  var e = document.getElementById("channel" + i);
  elements.push(e); 
}
```

Comment: You are still doing 100 calls to `getElementById` ;)

Comment: Sure, but at least you save some typing :-)

Comment: Can't argue with that :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes on your elements, say you add `class='channels'`. You can do something like this,

```
var channels = document.querySelectorAll(".channels");

for (var i = 0;  i < channels.length; i++) {
    var ch = channels[i]
    , ch_num = i

    ch.addEventListener('click', function () {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: publicSessionID,
            message: {
                "action": "tv.new.channel." + i
            } //use channel here
            uuid: sms,
            callback: function (info) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```